# How to show time from a column of timestamp type in table at BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a column named called "INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP".

I want to show the date and time format from that particular column.

So far I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT
 USERID as UserId,
 INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP,
 EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP) as IsoWeek,
 EXTRACT(DATE from INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP) as date,
 EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP)-1 as DayOfWeek,
 PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%H", INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP, "UTC") as Time;
 CONCAT(CAST(JOURNEY_ID AS STRING),"-", CAST(JOURNEY_ACTIONID AS STRING)) as JobId,
CASE 
 WHEN INTERACTION_TYPE = 0 THEN "open"
 WHEN INTERACTION_TYPE = 1 THEN "click"
 ELSE null
END AS Open_Click
FROM
 `XXXXXXXXX.database_name`
```

However, the BigQuery always thows an error message from that line of code:
`PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%H", INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP, "UTC") as Time;`

The error message says (as far as I could recall) that the `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` does not match with the syntax shown in this website: [PARSE_TIMESTAMP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp)

How do I handle the string from `INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP` so I could show the time value from the timestamp in BigQuery?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @ECris, the message says "failed to parse input string "2019-06-05 00:00:00+00" (error code: invaidQuery)"

Comment: Your column INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP is a TIMESTAMP and `PARSE_TIMESTAMP(format_string, string[, time_zone])`  works with STRING not TIMESTAMP.  Use  `EXTRACT(HOUR from ..)` to extract the hour.

Comment: Or better yet : `EXTRACT(TIME from INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Instead of `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` you should use `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP`

```
SELECT
 USERID as UserId,
 INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP,
 EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP) as IsoWeek,
 EXTRACT(DATE from INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP) as date,
 EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP)-1 as DayOfWeek,
 FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%H", INTERACTION_TIMESTAMP, "UTC") as Time,
 CONCAT(CAST(JOURNEY_ID AS STRING),"-", CAST(JOURNEY_ACTIONID AS STRING)) as JobId,
CASE 
 WHEN INTERACTION_TYPE = 0 THEN "open"
 WHEN INTERACTION_TYPE = 1 THEN "click"
 ELSE null
END AS Open_Click
FROM
 `XXXXXXXXX.database_name`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXTRACT function to extract time and pass the timezone like this

```
select EXTRACT(TIME FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') as Time;
```